# How to redirect to view from external JavaScript file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button click happening in an external JS file and I'm trying to get it redirect to another view. I am getting the ActionResult in the controller file but it doesn't want to move from the first view.

My code that I am using to get to the ActionResult is

```
$('#Req1').on('click', function () {
    console.log("Called");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/FruitStandHome/Requirement1",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        }
    });
});
```

and the action result in the controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Requirement1()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have a view already bound to this ActionResult, but as I say its not sending me to that view on the click event.

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong ;)

Comment: You cannot redirect using ajax. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page and ajax calls never redirect. You can however display the results of the view returned by your `Requirement1` method in the current page. If you want to redirect, then do not use ajax -make you button a link.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, is there any other ways to do this or is the button link the only way?

Comment: You could use `location.href='/FruitStandHome/Requirement1';` in the success callback of the ajax call. But that is just degrading performance. If you want to post data and redirect, use a form and a submit button, and in the method use `return RedirectToAction()` to redirect. But its not clear why your posting to `Requirement1()` which does not save any data.

Answer (score 1):

In your html create a container element in which the returned View html will be loaded, let's say that we have a div with id **viewcontainer**:

```
<div id="viewcontainer">
<!-- All html in here, possibly add this in _Layout.cshtml -->
</div>
```

and another thing is do not use hard-coded urls, instead use `Url.Action` helper for generating the correct urls and utilize `html5` data attribute following way:

```
<button id="Req1" data-url="@Url.Action("Requirement1","FruitStandHome")" />
```

Now in the success function of your ajax call update the content of div with the result of view returned from the server, you don't need to set the `content-type` to **JSON**, as the the controller action will be returning html and neither you need to set `datatype` to **JSON** as we are not passing any parameter for now, so just change your ajax call code to be:

```
$('#Req1').on('click', function () {
     console.log("Called");
     var url = $(this).data("url");
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         $("#viewcontainer").html(data);
       }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I gave it a shot and it will hit the actionresult but I am still on the originating view. I tried your earlier answer and the button took in the returned data

Comment: you need to put all the content of your view in a container div and n ajax call success just update the content of that container div